# Please help clear doubt about algebraic extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

This is from Artin's Algebra:

> [image]

I am very confused here: I can't figure out if they are contrasting para 1 above with prop 15.2.8 or generalizing para 1 in prop 15.2.8, or what?

Also, I can't see how $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$ and $\Bbb Q(\beta)$ are the same.

Comment: Plug $x-1$ instead of $x$ in the first equation. What are equal irreducible polynomials in this context?

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, the observation in § 1 is contrasting with Prop. 15.2.8, since   $\mathbf Q(\alpha)$ and $\mathbf Q(\alpha+1)$ are more than isomorphic: they're equal, yet $\alpha$ and $\alpha+1$ do not have the same irreducible polynomial. The difference lies in the fact that the map $x\rightsquigarrow x+1$ on $\mathbf Q(\alpha)$ is a field isomorphism,  but *not* a $\mathbf Q$-isomorphism.

As to your second question, note that $\alpha+1\in\mathbf Q(\alpha)$, whence a first inclusion, and that $ \alpha=(\alpha+1)-1$, whence the reverse inclusion.

Comment: The map $x\rightsquigarrow x+1$ on $\mathbf Q(\alpha)$ does not send $0$ to $0$ and so cannot be a field isomorphism.